# jQuery/css make two divs display on the same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given that I have the following html markup:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="divOne">One div</div>
  <div id="divTwo">
    <span id="spanTwo">
      <label>Input two:</label>
    <input type="text" id="inputTwo" />
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div id="divthree">
    <p>
      <label>selectOne</label>
      <span id="spanSelectOne">
        <select id="selectOne">
          <option value="opt1">Opt1</option>
          <option value="opt2">Opt2</option>       
        </select>
      </span>
      <span id="spanSelectTwo">
        <select id="selectOne">
          <option value="opt01">Opt01</option>
          <option value="opt02">Opt02</option>
        </select>
      </span>      
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make div **id="divTwo"** and div **id="divthree"** appear on the same line? First **divthree** and then **divTwo**, using jQuery or css?

**Update**:

I can't add divs or other elements to the html code, it is rendered like that and I can only change it using js or css.

Comment: Why do you need to use jquery? why not change the css?

Comment: @beginnerprogrammer sure i forgot to mention it. how can i do it using css?

Comment: just use `.align { float:left; }` and `clear {clear:both;}` somewhere in css and `<div class="clear"></div>` after `divthree`;

Comment: You don't really need jquery for this, but you can add `$('#divthree').css('float','left');` - so then you need to clear floats also.

Comment: could you suggest an answer with your solution? @dmitryro

Comment: If you know you're using bootstrap, you can also you can also use two `col-sm-6` or `col-xs-6` (12 unit grid) classes within `row` class within your `container` or `container-fluid` class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I updated my answer.
I use jQuery to append new div

```js
var $newdiv1 = $( "<div class='selectInput'></div>"),
  existingdiv2 = document.getElementById( "divTwo" ),
  existingdiv3 = document.getElementById( "divthree" );
 
$( ".container" ).append( $newdiv1);
$( ".selectInput" ).append( [ existingdiv3, existingdiv2 ] );
```

```css
.selectInput{
  display: flex;
}

#divthree{
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#divTwo{
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="divOne">One div</div>
  <div id="divTwo">
    <span id="spanTwo">
      <label>Input two:</label>
    <input type="text" id="inputTwo" />
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div id="divthree">
    <p>
      <label>selectOne</label>
      <span id="spanSelectOne">
        <select id="selectOne">
          <option value="opt1">Opt1</option>
          <option value="opt2">Opt2</option>       
        </select>
      </span>
      <span id="spanSelectTwo">
        <select id="selectOne">
          <option value="opt01">Opt01</option>
          <option value="opt02">Opt02</option>
        </select>
      </span>      
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle link for this code](https://jsfiddle.net/nvm1oyoj/1/)

Comment: i don't want to put all three on same line, i asked in the question that i want to put divTwo and divthree on the same line. So id="divOne" should be on its own, and two and three on the same line.

Comment: i see, thanks, i mentioned in the question that i can't manually add the extra div wrapper around the elements. it should be done using jquery or javacript. so your solution can't work.

Comment: I update it using jQuery function, check it out, hope it can help

Answer (score 1):

Change the display property to make them appear inline.

```
#divTwo, #divthree {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#divTwo, #divthree {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```